# Error de versiones de java con itext y pdfbox

Tags: java, pdf, gradle, itext, pdfbox2.0

Estoy intentando crear una aplicacion que coja los datos que yo meta y que estos esten en un PDF, lo estoy haciendo con javafx y utilizando el repositorio de maven de itext y de pdfbox

```
dependencies {

    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:${junitVersion}")
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:${junitVersion}")
    implementation 'com.itextpdf:itext7-core:8.0.0'
    implementation 'org.apache.pdfbox:pdfbox:3.0.0-RC1'
}
```

En una clase separada de la principal he puesto el siguiente codigo como prueba

```
package james.berrocal.proyectomama;

import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument;

import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter;

import com.itextpdf.layout.Document;

import javafx.scene.text.Font;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;


public class generarPDF {

     public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

         String ruta="generar.pdf";
         PdfWriter pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(ruta);
         PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(pdfWriter);
         pdfDocument.addNewPage();

         Document document = new Document(pdfDocument);

         document.close();

         System.out.println("pdf hecho :)");

     }
}
```

Pero al momento de ejecutar el programa, me salta al archivo module-info.java en donde me sale que todo hay error y que debo cambiar el nivel de lenguaje

```
module james.berrocal.proyectomama {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;


    opens james.berrocal.proyectomama to javafx.fxml;
    exports james.berrocal.proyectomama;
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estos son las versiones que utilizo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He probado a cambiar la version de java y de gradle pero he probado con varios y ninguno logro que funcione, estas son las versiones que he probado.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y este es el error que sale al probar con estas, solo se da al intentar ejecutar el programa:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

no se si cambia algo pero tambien puse esto en build.gradle porque si no, no iban ninguna de las funciones de itext ni de pdfbox, antes estaba en 11.

```
sourceCompatibility = 1.9
targetCompatibility = '1.9'
```

Soy nuevo usando Java así que no tengo ni idea de como funcionan las versiones y perdón si es que me dejo algo. Gracias por adelantado.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Debido a que estas usando la [última versión de iText](https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/releases/release-itext-core-8-0-0) (May 10, 2023), manten `sourceCompatibility` y `targetCompatibility` como tenías definido originalmente en tu proyecto, solo cambia "Languaje level" a 11,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

construye y prueba nuevamente tu proyecto con esto debería funcionar.